# How to use attach VM to Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have O365 and Azure Active Directory enabled. Domain is testcompany.com and user can login to O365 with firstname.lastname@testcompany.com

I know how to create virtual network and create virtual machine to it.
And I would like to Web App to support AD authentication.

However I don't know what I need to do to able to join VM to AD. Should I create Azure Domain Services next? I read several articles explaining different features but cannot see what are main steps to perform.

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create Azure Domain Services next?

Yes, we should enable Azure AD Domain Services.

Here are the steps:

1.[Create the `AAD DC Administrators` group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started)
2.[Create or select a virtual network for Azure Domain services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started)
3.[Enable Azure AD domain services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started)
4.[Update DNS settings for the Azure Virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started-dns)
5.[Enable password synchronization to AAD Domain Services for a cloud-only Azure AD tenant.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started-password-sync)

After completing the tasks above, you can a VM to the domain by referring to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-windows-vm).

Comment: In this case Azure AD is in production and I'm going this first time. Is there any risks of me to messing up Azure AD? I can just easily try to do suggested steps and remove all if I want to?

Comment: If you remove your AAD and AAD DS, we should reset virtual network DNS settings, and we need reboot your VM, no other risks. Please let me know if you need more help, also, if it helps, please don't forget to accept it as an answer so that other community will be benefited, thanks:)